# How do I get my ZWO ASI120MM astro-camera to work in MMA?

Tags: data-acquisition

I am using Windows 10 + MMA 10.4.1. I bought a ZWO ASI120MM astro camera which I want to use as a guiding camera during astrophotography. From this site (http://astronomy-imaging-camera.com/software/) I installed driver version 2.7 for the corresponding device and it now shows up in the device manager. The camera also works with the shipped software and I get moving & still images as I want to.

Problem: $ImagingDevices only shows a "USB 2.0 camera", which is my built-in laptop camera. FindDevices["Camera"] gives the same result. How can I now access my camera through Mathematica? I already tried using it under Linux with opencv, which also didn't work. For a start, importing 5 frames/sec via a commandline call or sth similar would be fine.

Thanks in advance!